# extract name entities and its corresponding numerical values from sentence

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I want to extract information from sentences.

Currently, I am able to do the following using spacy.

```
Amy's monthly payment is $2000. -->  (Amy's monthly payment, $2000)
```

However, I am trying to do the following.

```
The monthly payments for Amy, Bob, and Eva are $2000, $3000 and $3500 respectively.  
--> ((Amy's monthly payment, $2000), (Bob's monthly payment, $3000), (Eva's monthly payment, $3500))
```

Is there any way that I can perform the task using the NLP method through python library such as Spacy? 
The pattern of the sentence is not fixed. Using regular expressions is not working.

Thanks

Comment: You can use python [https://www.nltk.org/](https://www.nltk.org/) to clear out the stopwords like (the, and ...) and after that you can check the remaining words what pattern they have and try to create a map between names and numbers

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the spacy dependency parse you can see that conjunctions are shown in it:
[image]
So you will need to add some logic that takes into account this conjunction relationship when you iterate through the dependency parse tree. You could link the conjunctions like this:

```
conjunctions = set()
for span in doc:
    if span.dep == conj:
        conjunctions.add(span.head)
        conjunctions.add(span)
```

You can play around with the spacy dependency parse visualisations here: https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy?text=The%20monthly%20payments%20for%20Amy%2C%20Bob%2C%20and%20Eva%20are%20%242000%2C%20%243000%20and%20%243500%20respectively.&model=en_core_web_lg&cpu=1&cph=1

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is similar to what I do currently. But I am still having trouble matching Amy's monthly payment to $2000, and Bob for $3000. I am wondering if there is anything better than hard code the order.